# $f(x)$ irreducible in $F[x]$, $\alpha$ a root, show that if some odd degree term of $f(x)$ has nonzero coefficient then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $f(x)$ an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ and $\alpha$ a root of $f$ in some extension of $F$. Show that if some odd degree term of $f(x)$ has a nonzero coefficient, then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$.

I'm stuck trying to show that $\alpha \in F(\alpha^2)$ or $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)]=1$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $f(x)$ can be written as $xg(x^2)+h(x^2)$, where $g(x)$ is not the zero polynomial. We have then $\alpha g(\alpha^2)+h(\alpha^2)=0$. It follows that $\alpha=-\frac{h(\alpha^2)}{g(\alpha^2)}$.

Thus we conclude that $\alpha\in F(\alpha^2)$ unless $g(\alpha^2)=0$.

But $g(x^2)$ has degree less than the degree of $f$.

Comment: If $g(\alpha^2)=0$, our division would be in trouble. But we show that cannot be the case by seeing that $g(x^2)$ has degree less than the degree of $f$. Since $f$ is irreducible, it is a *minimal polynomial* for $\alpha$ over $F$. Thus we cannot have $g(\alpha^2)=0$.

Comment: Right, I asked that before you updated your post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way. I had probably spent over 2 hours working on this so I asked it on here, then in the 5 minutes it took for a response I came up with pretty much this exact solution.

Comment: You are welcome. A degree of the extension argument may work, but I am biased towards concrete abstract algebra.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind with the extension degree argument. If anyone has an extension degree argument I'd be interested to see it.